# Can the Data Import Handler be updated in Solr without having to re-deploy the collection again?

Tags: solr

I have a large solr collection that retrieves its data from postgres. It takes around 40 minutes to create from scratch. When it comes to altering the data import handler, I have been deleting the collection and then recreating it to test the changes made its configuration.

Is there a way to keep the collection and only update the dih?

Comment: You can just reload the collection if you want to update the DIH configuration; but no changes to your index content will take effect until you reindex the content in question.

Comment: @MatsLindh ok, but how do i go about setting the new config? can i do it through solr admin?

Comment: In standalone: you edit the file on disk/copy it to the location where it lives. In cloud: you upload it with zkcli and upconfig to Zookeeper.